# standard linux link to preferred file manager?

Tags: c, linux, gtk, desktop

I'm writing a GTK+ application. At the end of the program's running, it opens the user selected directory. Currently, it is hard-coded to open nautilus:

```
g_spawn_sync(
    0,
    stringArray(
        "/usr/bin/nautilus",
        gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(directoryChooser)),
        NULL
    ), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
gtk_main_quit();
```

I want this to work on other desktop environments where nautilus isn't necessarily installed or preferred. There are links to other programs in `/etc/alternatives` and links such as `x-terminal-emulator` and `x-www-browser` that are standardised.

Are there similar ways to get the preferred graphical file manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`gnome-open`](http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/12/16/gnome-open-open-anything-from-the-command-line/) will open a directory in the preferred file manager if you give it a directory name. It will also open up other preferred applications, such as a PDF viewer or broswer depending on what you pass it.

Another alternative is [`xdg-open`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html), which does a similar thing.

Comment: To be even more portable there's freedsktop's xdg-open

Comment: @johannes Which I mentioned at the end, but that opens directories in the browser. :/

Comment: Thanks! `xdg-open` is a nice standard command that works across DEs.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`gtk_show_uri()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-Filesystem-utilities.html#gtk-show-uri), then you won't have to bother with a spawned process.